# Trying to write a node.js script to batch rename files with regex and search/replace

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm trying to figure out what I think should be a fairly simple script, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.
I have a list of hundreds of files with names that aren't very easy to read that I want to try to rename to something easier to organize and understand.
What I need to be able to do is get a list of all the files in a directory, cycle through each file, get its filename, do some regex searching to get some information from the filename, then use that information to generate a new filename and rename the file, then move it to another directory (so that when the script is done, the old directory is empty and the new directory is full of the newly renamed files)

There is a pattern to the file names that can be easily matched with a regex to capture the data needed to generate the new file name.  I just need to know how to get each file, read its filename into a variable, process it, then use the data to rename the file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [fs.readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) to read the files of the directory and then use [fs.rename](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback) to rename them.

```
const fs = require("fs")

// Read directory
fs.readdir("./", (err, files) => {
  // Cicle files on current folder
  for (const file of files) {
    // Test regular expression
    if (/[A-Z]/g.test(file)) {
      // Add more logic to rename file
      fs.rename(file, 'newFile.txt', (err) => {
        console.log('Renaming', file, "to", "newFile.txt")
        if (err) throw err
      })
    }
  }
})
```